# Стоит ли продолжать начинания в изучении Python как основного?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне симпатизирует синтаксис, но язык кажется каким-то больше вспомогательным сам по себе. Да, есть фреймворки, но тот же Джанго относительно не столь популярен. Но на данный момент это единственный язык, который я знаю на начальном уровне, и стоит ли продолжать?

Не хочу ситуацию, чтоб я остался на улице, а PHP/C++/Java-элита бы пожинала плоды.

Comment: Python лучший язык, и множество библиотек на все случаи жизни.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Мнение

1. Python — не «вспомогательный» язык,
2. это популярный язык программирования,
3. продолжать изучение стоит,
4. на улице при соответствующем уровне знаний не останетесь.

---

### 2. Аргументация

#### 2.1. Рейтинги популярности языков программирования

1. [**PYPL**](http://pypl.github.io/PYPL.html) — второе место на февраль 2018;

   [image: PYPL]
2. [**Redmonk**](http://redmonk.com/sogrady/2017/06/08/language-rankings-6-17/) — третье место на июнь 2017;
3. [**TIOBE**](https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/) — четвёртое место на январь 2018;

   [image: TIOBE]
4. [**Trendy Skills**](https://trendyskills.com/) — пятое место на февраль 2018. Правда, на 4-м месте в этом рейтинге HTML, не являющийся языком программирования.

   [image: Trendy Skills]

#### 2.2.Рейтинги востребованности рабочих мест

1. [**Indeed**](http://www.codingdojo.com/blog/7-most-in-demand-programming-languages-of-2018/) — 2-е место на ноябрь 2017;

   [image: Indeed 1]
2. [**Indeed другая статистика**](https://stackify.com/popular-programming-languages-2018/) — 4-е место на декабрь 2017.

   [image: Indeed 2]

#### 2.3. Рейтинги языков программирования по зарплате разработчиков

1. [**ChallengeRocket**](https://medium.com/@ChallengeRocket/top-10-of-programming-languages-with-the-highest-salaries-in-2017-4390f468256e) — 3-е место на февраль 2017.

   [image: ChallengeRocket]

См. также перевод отрывка, посвящённого Python:

> Это универсальный и понятный язык, используемый крупными игроками в технологической индустрии (Google, NASA). Принимая во внимание, что уже в 2016 инженер-программист со знанием Python может заработать до $100 000, мы прогнозируем, что годовой оклад Senior Python Developer будет колебаться вокруг суммы $105 000 и выше. Это объясняется в значительной степени популярностью языка и его частым появлением в списках требований в процедурах найма на работу. Согласно рейтингу TIOBE, Python находится на 5-м месте по количеству запросов в основных поисковых системах, поэтому аналитики предполагают, что его популярность будет продолжать расти. За последние 5 лет популярность Python демонстрировала наибольшие темпы роста в этом аспекте (6,8%, когда, например, PHP имеет -5,0%).

---

### 3. Дополнительная информация

О том, как вычисляются рейтинги, в большинстве случаев можно посмотреть по ссылкам на эти рейтинги. См. также:

- [**Краткое описание, какие критерии берутся в расчёт для некоторых из перечисленных выше рейтингов**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measuring_programming_language_popularity#Indices).

Comment: Ого. Спасибо за развернутый ответ со статистикой.

Comment: @AlexFlow: [**вот этот ответ**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4881/199934) Вам, возможно, ещё пригодится. Там про С#, но принципы те же. Спасибо.

Comment: Понял, есть к чему стремиться :)

Answer (score 10):

Хороший специалист не останется на улице, независимо от того, в какой именно области он специалист. А плохой не сможет "пожинать плоды" даже используя самый популярный и востребованный язык.

Comment: По моему мнению человека, работавшего в довольно специфичной области, очень смелое и спорное утверждение, почему оставил минус. // **Во-первых**, в 90-х как раз и происходило, что специалисты не могли приспособиться к новым условиям и в буквальном смысле оказывались на улице. Не у всех такая психология, что легко удаётся перестроиться.

Comment: Хорошо, сравнивать 90-е с современной ситуацией именно в программировании — некорректная аналогия. Но **во-вторых**, представим программиста на условном [**Forth**](https://www.forth.com/forth/). Когда ты супер-мега профессионал, то при потере работы будет относительно меньше трудностей в поиске новой в области, использующей данный язык. А вот если специалист рангом пониже, вероятно, придётся переучиваться. Тут как раз имеют значение популярность и востребованность языка.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Если ты думаешь что python из-за своей простоты(более менее читаемый код это его преимущество) язык для начинающих и особой пользы не несет то ты ошибаешься.

Во первых Google использует питон в своей поисковой системе, компания irobot использует питон для разработки коммерческих военных роботов. Также Pixar, intel, IBM, cisco, NASA, JBL и другие компании используют питон для разных задач.

Я бы не сказал что python вспомогательный язык программирования. Да для большинства робот в компаниях тебе понадобятся и другие языки программирования(ибо я пока ещё не нашёл компанию там где надо было знать всего лишь один пайтон). Но все же python как для начала так и для будущего надо выучить.

Comment: Ну, например, в Google можно попасть зная только Python (из языков программирования) ;-)

Comment: Звучит перспективно. Спасибо

Comment: Но только для работы в Google его надо знать супер-хорошо, включая всякие алгоритмы и пр. Дерзайте!

Answer (score 2):

Судя по моим наблюдениям, количество Python-вакансий растет, особенно, если связаться с такими областями как Data Mining или Deep Learning. Сейчас там Python и R прямо правят бал. Так что врубайтесь в питон посильнее и получше и вперед! Без куска хлеба с икрой не останетесь. Кроме того, если по-хорошему освоить Python и понять как вообще работает программирование, то остальные языки пойдут полегче.